# How to add html page to Tab in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have one tab with `class=plots-tabs-heatmap`. I am trying to add one page to this tab using following code but i see not **tmpdata/page2.html** as output on tab.

```
$('#plots-tabs-heatmap').html("tmpdata/page2.html");
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`html()` will not retrieve files from server.

You want `load()` which is an ajax method

```
$('.plots-tabs-heatmap').load("tmpdata/page2.html");
```

This is a shorthand method forr `$.ajax` that makes the request and also inserts the response html within the referenced selector used

reference: [load() api docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: you missed one important thing though - `I have one tab with class=plots-tabs-heatmap`

Comment: But i got no output when using highchart code in html.  http://www.filedropper.com/heatmap

Comment: you need to initialize that code in complete callback of `load()` or the code in the file needs to be after the html it references. `document.ready` won't matter here because it occurred a long time ago when main page loaded. Post relevant code structure in question. nobody downloads unknown files here and it is time consuming

Comment: My Html code is already in http://jsfiddle.net/ufxyf6qt/22/ can u pls post an example where i can use this code in tab.